# Array in hive and hbase

Tags: arrays, hive, hbase

I created a hbase table and it's hive external table.

I need to define 3 arrays : an array of `bytes` and an array of `int` an array of `string` !
I put them in 3 column in hbase and want to access them in hive .

I defined in many ways but didn't got any good result (also use `explode()` ) but result in string array was like a string and in the others was `NULL` .

How do i put them in hbase ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it by this code :

```
                    Put p =new Put(Bytes.toBytes("12345"));
                    byte delimiter = 0x02;

                    byte[] a1=Bytes.toBytes("ali");
                    byte[] bytes = new byte[2*a1.length+1];
                    //byte[] a1=Bytes.toBytes("ali");
                    int i=0;
                    for( i=0;i<a1.length;i++){
                        bytes[i]=a1[i];
                    }
                    bytes[i]=delimiter;

                    p.add(INFO_FAMILY,Bytes.toBytes("arr"),bytes);
                    hTableInterface.put(p);
```